# Conditional expectation of minimum of exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent exponentially distributed random variables with parameter $\theta > 0$. I want to compute $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1]$, where $X_1 \wedge X_2 := \min(X_1, X_2)$.

I'm really not sure how to do this. I don't want to use any joint distribution formulas (that's a different exercise in this text). Basically all I know about conditional expectations is that $\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E[X | Y] \mathbb 1_A \right] = \mathbb E[X \mathbb 1_A]$, for any $A \in \sigma(Y)$. I thought about using this property to calculate $\mathbb E\left[(X_1 \wedge X_2) \mathbb 1_{\{X_1 \leq X_2\}}| X_1\right]$ and $\mathbb E\left[(X_1 \wedge X_2) \mathbb 1_{\{X_1 > X_2\}}| X_1\right]$ separately, but it's not clear to me that either of these sets are necessarily in $\sigma(X_1)$. Any hints?

**Edit**: I want to avoid using conditional probability over expectations while conditioning over zero-probability events. That's a different section of the book I'm reading out of (Achim Klenke's "Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course").

**Edit 2**: I eventually found my own solution, which I've posted as an answer below.

Comment: You cannot answer this without any independence assumption.

Comment: Assuming independence, you might to try to find $\mathbb E[k \wedge X_2 ]$ for some constant $k \ge 0$

Comment: Ah yes, they are independent. I edited it.

Comment: @Henry I'm not sure how that helps if we assume independence. Is there an independence property you're invoking?

Comment: With independence, knowing $X_1=k$ tells you nothing new about the distribution of $X_2$, so my hint is helpful.  Without independence, my suggestion would not help with the original question

Comment: Right, but $\mathbb P[X_1=k] = 0$. The book I'm using hasn't introduced conditioning on zero-probability events, so I'd like to avoid attempting to calculate $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = k]$. Also, that's the conditional expectation over a single event. I'm trying to calculate $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1] := \mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | \sigma(X_1)]$. If I knew $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = k]$ for every $k > 0$, would there be a way to then find $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1] $?

Answer (score 2):

$$
E[X_1\wedge X_2|X_1=s]=\int_0^\infty (t\wedge s)\hspace{-.5cm}\underbrace{\theta e^{-\theta t}}_{\text{conditional pdf}\\\text{of $X_2$ given $X_1=s$}}\hspace{-.5cm}\,dt=\int_0^st\theta e^{-t\theta}\,dt+\int_s^\infty s\theta e^{-t\theta}\,dt
$$

Comment: See my above comment: $\mathbb P[X_1 = s] = 0$ for each fixed $s$, and I'd prefer to avoid conditioning on zero-probability events. Plus I'm not sure how to calculate $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1] $ from knowing $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = s]$ for any given $s$.

Comment: @DFord The above calculation will give you the correct answer, and then you can prove it is correct by showing it satisfies $E[E[X_1\wedge X_2|X_1]1_A]=E[X_1\wedge X_2\cdot 1_A]$ for all $A\in \sigma(X_1)$.

Comment: Also, $E[X_1\wedge X_2|X_1=s]$ works out to be $f(s)$ for some function $s$. Then $E[X_1\wedge X_2|X_1]=f(X_1)$. @DFord

Comment: If $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = s] = f(s)$, wouldn't it follow that $f(X_1) = \mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = X_1] = \mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2]$?

Comment: @DFord It doesn't quite work like that. If $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ is the cdf of a random variable $X$, do you conclude $F(X)=P(X\le X)=1$? No, $F(X)$ is just another random variable, which takes values between $0$ and $1$. Same kind of thing here.

Comment: No I know it doesn't quite work that way, but I wasn't familiar with the calculation involved in showing that if $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 = s] = f(s)$, then $\mathbb E[X_1 \wedge X_2|X_1] = f(X_1)$. (As it turned out, that was the very next section of the textbook I'm using.)

Answer (score 1):

Here you are an other way to see it (to not condition on zero probability events).

The conditional expectation with respect to a continuous random variable $\mathbb{E}[X\mid Y]$ can be defined as  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation)
\begin{align}
g(y)=\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\mathbb{E} [ X| \{\omega: \|Y(\omega)-y \|\le \epsilon\} ]
\end{align}
Applying this to your case and letting $H_{\epsilon,y}=\{\omega: |X_1(\omega)-y |\le \epsilon\}$, we get
\begin{align}
g(y)
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\mathbb{E} [ X_1 \vee X_2 \mid H_{\epsilon,y} ] \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{\mathbb{E} [ (X_1 \vee X_2) I_{H_{\epsilon,y}} ]}{P(H_{\epsilon,y} )} \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac
{
% \mathbb{E} [ (X_1 \vee X_2) I_{H_{\epsilon,y}} ]
\int_{\mathbb{R}_+^2} (x_1 \vee x_2) I_{\{|x_1-y |\le \epsilon\}} \theta e^{-\theta x_1} \theta e^{-\theta x_2} {\rm d }x
}
{\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} \theta e^{-\theta z}{\rm d }z} \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac
{
% \mathbb{E} [ (X_1 \vee X_2) I_{H_{\epsilon,y}} ]
\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} \int_{\mathbb{R}_+} (x_1 \vee x_2) \theta e^{-\theta x_1} \theta e^{-\theta x_2} {\rm d }x_2{\rm d }x_1
}
{
e^{-\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-\theta(y+\epsilon)}
} \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac
{
\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} 
\theta e^{-\theta x_1} 
% 
\left(
\int_{0}^{x_1} x_2\theta e^{-\theta x_2} {\rm d }x_2
+
 x_1 \int_{x_1}^{\infty} \theta e^{-\theta x_2} {\rm d }x_2
\right)
% 
{\rm d }x_1
}
{
e^{-\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-\theta(y+\epsilon)}
} \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac
{
\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} 
e^{-2\theta x_1} 
% 
\left(
 e^{\theta x_1} - \theta x_1 -1
+
 \theta x_1 
\right)
% 
{\rm d }x_1
}
{
e^{-\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-\theta(y+\epsilon)}
} \\
% 
& =\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac{1}{\theta }
\frac
{
\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} 
\theta e^{-\theta x_1}
{\rm d }x_1
-
\int_{y-\epsilon}^{y+\epsilon} 
\theta e^{-2\theta x_1}
{\rm d }x_1
}
{
e^{-\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-\theta(y+\epsilon)}
} \\
% 
& = 
\frac{1}{\theta }-
\frac{1}{2\theta }
\lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
\frac
{
e^{-2\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-2\theta(y+\epsilon)}
}
{
e^{-\theta(y-\epsilon)} -e^{-\theta(y+\epsilon)}
} \\
% 
% & = 
% \frac{1}{\theta }-
% \frac{e^{-\theta y}}{2\theta }
% \lim _{\epsilon \to 0}
% \frac
% {
% e^{2\theta \epsilon} - 1  - (e^{-2\theta \epsilon} -1)
% }
% {
% e^{ \theta \epsilon} -1 - (e^{- \theta \epsilon}-1)
% } \\
& = 
\frac{1}{\theta }-
\frac{e^{-\theta y}}{2\theta }
\times
\frac
{
4 \theta
}
{
2 \theta
} \\
& = 
\frac{1-e^{-\theta y}}{\theta }
\end{align}

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, that's the answer I got. Though I ended up finding it using image measures and densities instead of explicit limits, although I like your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We're looking for a $\sigma(X_1)$-measurable function $\mathbb E\left[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1\right] : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ for which for every $A \in \sigma(X_1)$,
$$
\mathbb E\left[\left(X_1 \wedge X_2\right) \mathbb 1_A\right] = \mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[ X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1 \right] \mathbb 1_A \right].
$$
Let $f_\theta(x) = \theta e^{-\theta x}$ be the probability density of $X_1$ and of $X_2$, and let $\lambda_n$ denote the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure. Then $f_\theta \, d\lambda_1 = d\left(\mathbb P \circ X_1^{-1}\right)$. Furthermore, by independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$, the joint probability density is $\tilde f(x,y) = \theta^2 e^{-\theta(x+y)}$, and $d\left(\mathbb P \circ \left(X_1 \times X_2 \right)^{-1}\right) = \tilde f \, d\lambda_2$, where $X_1 \times X_2 : \Omega \to \mathbb R^2$ is $\omega \mapsto \left(X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega)\right)$. Let $A \in \sigma(X_1)$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E\left[\left(X_1 \wedge X_2 \right)\mathbb 1_A \right] &= \int_A X_1 \wedge X_2 \, d\mathbb P = \int_{X_1(A) \times [0,\infty)} x \wedge y \, d\left(\mathbb P \circ \left(X_1 \times X_2 \right)^{-1}\right) \\
&= \int_{X_1(A)} \int_0^\infty \left(x \wedge y\right) \theta^2 e^{-\theta(x+y)} \, dy \, dx\\ &= \int_{X_1(A)} \int_0^x \theta^2 ye^{-\theta(x+y)} \, dy \, dx + \int_{X_1(A)} \int_x^\infty \theta^2 x e^{-\theta(x+y)} \, dy \, dx \\
&= \int_{X_1(A)} \left(-\theta x e^{-2\theta x} - e^{-2\theta x} + e^{-\theta x}\right) \, dx + \int_{X_1(A)} \theta x e^{-2\theta x}\,dx \\
&= \int_{X_1(A)} \left(e^{-\theta x} - e^{-2\theta x}\right)\,dx = \int_{X_1(A)} \frac 1 \theta \left(1-e^{-\theta x}\right)\theta e^{-\theta x}\,dx \\
&= \int_{X_1(A)} \frac 1 \theta \left(1-e^{-\theta x}\right) \, d\left(\mathbb P \circ X_1^{-1}\right)(x) = \int_A \frac 1 \theta \left(1-e^{-\theta X_1}\right) \, d\mathbb P \\
&= \mathbb E\left[\frac 1 \theta \left(1-e^{-\theta X_1}\right) \mathbb 1_A \right].
\end{align*}
The second of the above equalities follows from the fact that $F \circ (X_1 \times X_2) = \left(X_1 \wedge X_2\right)\mathbb{1}_A$, where $F(x,y) = \left(x \wedge y\right)\mathbb{1}_{X_1(A) \times [0,\infty)}(x,y)$.
From this it follows that $\boxed{\mathbb E\left[X_1 \wedge X_2 | X_1\right] = \frac 1 \theta \left(1-e^{-\theta X_1}\right).}$